# Find the Nth number of a even-only digits

Tags: algorithm

Consider the We are having `{0,2,4,6,8}` digits only. Now we have to find the N numbers of a series.

```
Series : 0,2,4,6,8,20,22,24,26,28,40.....

int start=0;
while(found!=n){

      if(start is not odd)found++;
      start+=2;
}
```

How can we do that efficiently ?

```
For Ex N=6  Ans=20
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? How efficient is the solution you found so far?

Comment: Have a look Intercept and Except

Comment: You probably mean the *first* N numbers?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem updated it

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to make up a number from 5 digits, so this is essentially a base-5 number, just with a quirky set of digits - {0, 2, 4, 6 ,8} instead of  {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}. Note that each digit in the required digit set is double the digit in the corresponding index of the base-5 digit set. So, to make a long story short, you could convert N to base 5 and then double the result. E.g., in Java (or C/C++, funnily enough):

```
int createNumber(int n) {
    int result = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        result *= 10;
        result += (n % 5);
        n /= 5;
    }
    return result * 2;
}
```

Comment: your code will find the number in reverse order and even worst if nth number ends with 0

Comment: What would we do say if the digits were not exactly double but random? Say: 0, 3, 4, 7, 8?

Answer (score 1):

Considering 0,2,4,6,8 as 0,1,2,3,4 we can see that you need to calculate the base-5 representation of N, and then replace the digits accordingly. The time complexity will be O(log5(N))

```
// N stores a value in base 10
   // solution will have digits in an array
   index = 0 ;
   while (N != 0)
   {
      remainder = N % 5 ;
      N = N / 5 ;
      digit[index] = remainder * 2; //0 = 2*0, 2 = 2*1, 4=2*2, etc
      index ++ ;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Detailed Explanation:**

Convert `N->N-1` to exclude `0`.

Let `A = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}`

Let's count how many numbers have `k`, `(k > 1)` digits and all their digits belong to set `{0, 2, 4, 6, 8}`. First digits can be chosen in `4` ways, all other digits in `5` ways, so in total, `4*pow(5, k-1)`. Which means, if `m = ceil(log5(N))`, then `N`th number in series has m digits.

Now, if the first digit in `base-5` representation of `N` equals `i`, `(1 <= i <= 4)` then first digit in our answer is `A[i]`. Same holds second digit and so on.

So in your algorithms you need to present `N` in `base-5`, e.g. `N=abcde..`, where each of `a,b,c` is in range `[0..4]` and ur answer will be a result of mapping each of `a` -> `A[a]`

Answer (score -2):

You could use a permutation algorithm and then sort it in ascending order. Using this, even if you add more digits to your sample space, the series would still work. See- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap's_algorithm

Note: Using a permutation for something so simple is overboard. But if you are looking for an algorithm which can take more digits and form a series, then permutation is a good way to use.

Comment: Why the downvote??

Comment: This is not a correct answer. There are *n!* permutations of a set, but there are infinite numbers base-5. These two things are related, but are not at all the same.